# Avoiding SVN recursive checkout of externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have a super-project which `svn:externals` several other projects.  They, in turn `svn:external` their own dependencies.  One of my issues is that my dependencies often depend on the same `svn:external` (common library) which leads to a lot of duplicated checking out and building.

When I checkout or update my main project, I'd like to checkout my immediate externals, but ignore their externals. I would imagine that I'd be able to set this in the svn property, but I haven't figured out how yet.  I would imagine something like this:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals -r25 http://svn.example.com/foo/trunk foo --ignore-externals
Subcommand 'propset' doesn't accept option '--ignore-externals'
Type 'svn help propset' for usage.
```

Is there another way to avoid checking out externals of externals?  `--depth` doesn't really work because the depth of the folder structure in my parent or intermediate repositories are arbitrary and so you can't reliably filter out externals with that command.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, I would appreciate knowing how as I am having a similar problem.

Comment: Nope, no solution yet.  I've had to just live with multiple checkouts of much lower-level solutions.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that anything starting with a `-` is treated as an option by the propget command (and so not stored in the external). You're also missing the path of them item that should get the property (probably "`.`")
You can use `--` to tell propget to stop processing options, so `svn propset -- svn:externals "-r25 /path/to/external my-external" .` should work (and store the -r25 in the property).
However, the other part of what you want is simply not (yet) supported by externals - you cannot limit the depth of the external, or ignore its externals.